# Getting same values using srnd

Tags: c++

im trying to crete a game of cards, and im getting this problem:

For example: Im drawing 3 cards to start the game, every time I play, the game gives the 2 of hearts and the 4 of diamonds, then the 3rd card is different(7 of diamonds for example). If I chose to get one more card the game keeps 2 of hearts, 4 of diamonds and swaps the 7 of diamonds with another card, instead of keeping it. Every time I draw one more it swaps the last one drawn on the last turn.

Output:
1st iteration

### Card board. Getting 3 initial cards

2 of hearts  4 of diamonds  7 of diamonds

Chose what do you want to do:

1.-Draw a card

2.-Chose a pair

1

2nd iteration

### Drawing a card

2 of hearts  4 of diamonds  9 of spades  2 of diamonds

Chose what do you want to do:

1.-Draw a card

2.-Chose a pair

1

3rd iteration

### Drawing a card

2 of hearts  4 of diamonds  9 of spades  7 of diamonds  2 of spades

Chose what do you want to do:

1.-Draw a card

2.-Chose a pair

And so on.

Thank you beforehand.

```
Card* Deck::pickCard() {
    Deck b;
    srand(time(NULL));
    int randCard = rand() % getMany()+1;
    Card* c;
    c = deck[randCard];
    for(int i=randCard+1;i<posFullDeck;i++){
        deck[i-1] = deck[i];
    }
    posFullDeck--;
    return c;
}

void TaulaJoc::pickCard() {
    if (getManyTable() < 20) {
        Baralla b;
        Carta *c = b.pickCard();
        //Eliminar del munt
        table[posFullTable] = c;
        posFullTable++;
        //DELETE
        delete c;
    } else if (getManyTable() == 20) {
        cout<<"You cannot draw more cards!"<<endl;
    }    
}
```

Comment: You should only call `srand` *once*. It is commonly done early in `main`.

Comment: So what is your question? (And note that "*why isn't my code working?*" type of question is off-topic for SO - you need to debug your code).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
Srand(time(0))
```

This should be called once at the beginning of main to change the variables each time the program is run. Then just use the rand function as you normally would, which you did not include in your code.

Comment: Good advice, but does that answer OP:s question?

Comment: I guess since he puts it inside the class function then everytime it is called the seed will change and then cause malfunctions in the statements he is calling.

Comment: Also the code given is not understandable since we are missing a lot of information on different weirdly named functions.

Comment: How's that? Even if `rand()` returns the same value, like `0`, over and over again, OP removes the chosen card and decreases `posFullDeck`. I agree that it's not a fully understandable / answerable question.

Answer (score -1):

You only have to call

```
srand(time(NULL));
```

only once, for example in the main function. Otherwise you will seed the random generator over and over again and get poor results.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/srand

Comment: This is more or less the same as @GChouchani's answer and I don't see how this answers OP:s question either.